# Functions calling functions in Python

Tags: python

```
def one_good_turn(n):
    return n + 1

def deserves_another(n):
    return n + 2
```

I don't quite understand when it is asked me change the body of deserves_another, so that it always adds 2 to the output of one_good_turn?

Comment: I don't quite understand, too.

Comment: Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is how to call a function from within another one

```
def one_good_turn(n):
    return n + 1

def deserves_another(n):
    return one_good_turn(n) + 2

n = 1
print one_good_turn(n)
print deserves_another(n)
```